# IE Conditional Comments: lt IE 7 = lte IE 6?

Tags: internet-explorer, comments, conditional-statements

Are there any differences using

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>...<![endif]-->
```

or

```
<!--[if lte IE 6]>...<![endif]-->
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they do the same thing.

Here's a [reference from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 4):

There will be a difference if a rare, mythological species of browser dubbed as **Internet Explorer 6.66** is found.

Comment: We've actually been secretly using IE6 this whole time. I hear Microsoft's internal version control for its current release of IE is 6.6.6.5.3.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose they're the same. `foo < 5` is the same as `foo <= 4`.

Maybe that if there were numbered versions of IE6 it would be different (like IE6.2 or something), but as far as I know it's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

They should be the same... lte 6 includes 6 on down, lt 7 includes anything before 6.